# Walkthrough: sum 2 integers using bit manipulation

Tags: bit-manipulation

I am trying to understand the logic behind the following code which sums 2 integers using bit manipulation:

```
def sum(a, b):
    while b != 0:
        carry = a & b
        a = a ^ b
        b = carry << 1

    return a
```

As an example I used: `a = 11` and `b = 7`

11 in binary representation is `1011`
7 in binary representation is `0111`

Then I walked through the algorithm:

```
iter #1: a = 1011, b = 0111
  carry = 0011 (3 decimal)
  a = 1100 (12 decimal)
  b = 0110 (6 decimal)

iter #2: a = 1100, b = 0110
  carry = 0100 (4 decimal)
  a = 1010 (10 decimal)
  b = 1000 (8 decimal)

iter #3: a = 1010, b = 1000
  carry = 1000 (8 decimal)
  a = 00010 (2 decimal)
  b = 10000 (16 decimal)

iter #4: a = 00010, b = 10000
  carry = 00000 (0 decimal)
  a = 10010 (18 decimal)
  b = 00000 (0 decimal)

We Done (because b is now 0).
```

As we can see, in all iterations `a+b` is always 18 which is the right answer.
However I failed to understand what is actually happens here. The value of `a` is going down and down with each iteration until suddenly pops to 18 in the last iteration. Also, can we learn anything from the value of the carry during the process?

I would love to understand the intuition behind this.

---

Thanks to @WJS answer I think I got it.

```
let's add 11 and 7 as before, but let's do it in the following order:
First, calculate it without the carry.
Second, calculate only the carry.
Then add both parts.

01011
00111
-----
01100 (neglecting carry)
00110 (finding only the carry)
-----
10010 (sum)
```

Now, to find the first part, how can we get rid of the carry bits? with XOR.
To find the second part, we use AND and then shift it 1 bit left to place it "under" the right bit.
Now all we have to do is sum both parts. The whole point is not using + operator so how can we do that? Recursion!

We assign the first part to `a` and the second part to `b` and we repeat this process until `b=0` which means we are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps if you take a simpler example it will help.

```
a = 11
b = 11
a & b == 11 since AND returns 1's where both bits in the same
position are 1. These are the carry bits.

Now get rid of the the carry locations using exclusive or
a = a ^ b == 00

But a `carry` would cause addition to add bits one position to
the left so shift the carry bits left by 1 bit.

b = carry << 1 = 110
now repeat the process

carry = a & b = 0 & 110 == 0 no more carries
b = carry << 1 == 0
done.
11 + 11 = 110 = 3 + 3 = 6
```

Understanding the roles of (AND) & and (XOR) ^ are key.  Applying those to slightly more complex examples should help. But ignore the interim decimal values as they don't help much.  Think only about what is happening in binary.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now. I edited the original question and refer to your answer. Take a look and tell me if I indeed got it correctly. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is easy to understand if you look at what happens with individual bits.

First step is calculating carry which only happens in binary when both bits are 1, so a&b calculates that for every bit. Then bitwise addition is happening via XOR (ignoring carry), and XOR works because:

```
0+0=0 (==0^0)
1+0=1 (==1^0)
1+1=0 (==1^1, generates carry bit which we ignore)
```

Next step is to shift carry to the left (<<1), move it to b and repeat until carry is empty.

Comment: Thank you. It is indeed the way I ended up with as you can see in original post edit.